# HTML5 audio player visualization

Tags: javascript, html

i'm working on a HTML5 audio player, and i'm stuck at making audio visualizations... I was googling and i only found visualizations that are supported by firefox or chrome. So now i'm here asking: is it possible to create audio visualizations with HTML5 and Javascript for all newest browsers?
If the anwser is yes: how?
If the anwser is no: what can you recomend then?

Comment: @Joseph it's not about what is good to implement a browser based visualizer but a question about **how** to implement one in HTML5. I know it's a broad question he asked but you can at least show him what he has to google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No. You're going to need a combination of the web audio API, and
   either canvas or webgl for the rendering. As you've discovered, the web audio API is
   only partially supported in [Chrome, Firefox and Safari](http://caniuse.com/#feat=audio-api).
2. Flash. It has a very capable sound API and is supported in all the newest desktop browsers (as well as the older ones).

[This bloke](http://blog.nihilogic.dk/2010/04/html5-audio-visualizations.html), who appears to post quite frequently on HTML5 audio, has worked around the lack of support for the web audio API by pre-processing his audio data and saving it as JavaScript. Depending on your requirements, this may be an option.

Answer (score 2):

No, as of now it does not look possible for all browsers.  I recommend dancer.js for your requirement. Check out the demo at http://jsantell.github.com/dancer.js/#